# Typescript - type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm using Vue.js with TypeScript and have run into some errors when using dynamic object keys. Here is my function:

```
  methods: {
    interface ResetStateItems {
      selected: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[];
      selectedDirectory: string;
      artifacts: WebspaceBackupArtifactExtended[];
      isLoadingDirectory: boolean;
      restoreComplete: boolean;
      isProcessingBackupRestore: boolean;
    }

    resetPage() {
      const resetStateItems: ResetStateItems = {
        selected: [],
        selectedDirectory: '/',
        artifacts: [],
        isLoadingDirectory: false,
        restoreComplete: false,
        isProcessingBackupRestore: false,
      };

      Object.keys(resetStateItems).forEach((stateItem: string) => {
        this[stateItem as keyof resetStateItems] = resetStateItems[stateItem];
      });
      this.getWebspaceBackupByWebspaceIdAndId();
    },
```

Here are the errors that I get:

```
ERROR in /app/src/views/BackupAndRestore/BackupAndRestoreWebspaceBackup.vue(484,9):
my-project    | 484:9 Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
my-project    |     482 |
my-project    |     483 |       Object.keys(resetStateItems).forEach((stateItem: string) => {
my-project    |   > 484 |         this[stateItem as keyof ResetStateItems] = resetStateItems[stateItem];
my-project    |         |         ^
my-project    |     485 |       });
my-project    |     486 |       this.getWebspaceBackupByWebspaceIdAndId();
my-project    |     487 |     },
```

```
ERROR in /app/src/views/BackupAndRestore/BackupAndRestoreWebspaceBackup.vue(484,52):
> my-project    | 484:52 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ResetStateItems'.
> my-project    |   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'ResetStateItems'.
> my-project    |     482 |
> my-project    |     483 |       Object.keys(resetStateItems).forEach((stateItem: string) => {
> my-project    |   > 484 |         this[stateItem as keyof ResetStateItems] = resetStateItems[stateItem];
> my-project    |         |                                                    ^
> my-project    |     485 |       });
> my-project    |     486 |       this.getWebspaceBackupByWebspaceIdAndId();
> my-project    |     487 |     },
```

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is as I have defined the interface `ResetStateItems` and thought I could just use `keyof` to make it work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what research you've done and any attempts you've made based on that research. For instance, [searching on your title returns 134 results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Typescript+-+type+%27string%27+can%27t+be+used+to+index+type), none of which are mentioned in the question.

Comment: I did actually I my research said I had to define an interface called `ResetStateItems ` which I did and couldn't get past the new error

Comment: If you click on that second link in my comment, you'll see many ways to "get past the new error".

Comment: I've obviously tried based off of examples other people have posted on here and not managed to get it to work. It takes longer to write out a question on here than copy someone elses solution and adapt it so I would have done that if I could have made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the variable name with the `keyof` statement, use the interface name:

```
this[stateItem as keyof ResetStateItems] = resetStateItems[stateItem];
```

Comment: Thank you but I am still left with the remaining two errors, one of which refers to using a string as the index